# Django post save signal getting called twice despite uid

Tags: python, mysql, django, signals

I have registered my signal with the callback using the `@receiver` decorator

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='ARandomUniqueString') 
def do_callback(sender, **kwargs):
```

I have put the `from app.signals import *` code in `__init__.py` and I can see that it gets imported twice and I do not think there is a good way to fix it, possibly happening due to `installed apps` in `settings.py`. I cannot understand why despite using `dispatch_uid` and the `modelInstance.save` being invoked only once, it still runs `do_callback` twice. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok so I moved the import to `views.py` (or `models.py` and while it was getting imported only once, it was getting called twice.

The problem was that the `post_save` signal was getting called when the object was created as well as saved. I have no idea why so I added a workaround which now works

```
created = False

    #Workaround to signal being emitted twice on create and save
    if 'created' in kwargs:
        if kwargs['created']:
            created=True

    #If signal is from object creation, return
    if created:
        return
```

Edit:

`post_save` was getting called twice because I used `.create(...)` which is equivalent to `__init__(...)` and `.save()`.

**Conclusion**

**`dispatch_uid` does work and doing single imports is still a good practice.**

Comment: How to differentiate between __init__ when created = False, and when we update/modify an object which also returns created=False?

Comment: @Pratik Mandrekar which file did you put the workout if statement in? I think I may be facing a problem now similar to what you face back then.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with post_save and also post_delete signals.  It seems that the session object and LogEntry object were being saved as well creating multiple signals despite setting the dispatch_uid.

What worked for me was:

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

....

if sender in [LogEntry, Session]:
    return 
else:
    # do your thing here
```

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered the same problem. I have a receiver that does something important which must be done only once for each new creation of a model instance in Django. So, I used the `post_save` signal, but that was being called twice for the creation of each new model instance which I was doing like `Profile.objects.create(...)`.
The solution to this problem is the `created` flag which comes with `kwargs`. Here's how you can use that flag to make sure your intended action is taken only once:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile)
def publish_auction(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        kwargs['instance'].send_email_confirmation()
```

I tried the `dispatch_uid` suggestion from [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals). It didn't work, but the code I pasted above works.

Answer (score 1):

> I have put the `from app.signals import *` code in `__init__.py`

You should not put anything in your `__init__.py` file.

If you remove this from `__init__.py`, and add it to the bottom of your `models.py`, it should solve your problem.

You should also avoid "blind" imports `from foo import *`

Comment: My `signals.py` uses `models.py` and while there is stuff I could do to avoid this circular dependency it goes against the flow. Solved it my only importing the `do_callback` in `__init__.py` instead of doing `from app.sgnals import *`