# Why does `post_save` signal get emitted on object creation along with object save?

Tags: python, django, django-models, signals

I had a problem with `post_save` being called twice and I spent a lot of time figuring out the imports as had been mentioned. I confirmed that the import is happening only once and there is no question of multiple registrations. Besides I'm using a unique `dispatch_uid` in the signal registration which as per the documentation should have solved the problem. It did not. I looked more carefully and saw that the signal handler gets called on .create() as well as .save(). Why for create?

The only way I could get it to work is by relying on the hack below inside my signal handler

```
created = False

    #Workaround to signal being emitted twice on create and save
    if 'created' in kwargs:
        if kwargs['created']:
            created=True

    #If signal is from object creation, return
    if created:
        return
```

This is a follow up to question [Django post save signal getting called twice despite uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012887/django-post-save-signal-getting-called-twice-despite-uid/12013253#12013253)

Comment: Presumably you want a better answer than "because creation is instantiation plus saving"?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Is MyClass.objects.create(...) different from just initializing MyClass(...) in general or specifically to signals? I have been thinking both ways of creation to be the same and wondering why it doesn't obey `Note that instantiating a model in no way touches your database; for that, you need to save().`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Because "creation" is instantiation plus saving.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create)

> **`create(**kwargs)`**
>
> A convenience method for creating an object and saving it all in one step. Thus:
>
> ```
> p = Person.objects.create(first_name="Bruce", last_name="Springsteen")
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> p = Person(first_name="Bruce", last_name="Springsteen")
> p.save(force_insert=True)
> ```
>
> are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! I should have known but had to go down till the signals to figure it out!