# How to add two values and save them with post_save signals

Tags: python, django

I'm using signals in models.py but when I make a sum this function does it twice instead of just a sum

models.py:

```
class Articulo(models.Model):
cod_experto = models.CharField(max_length=999, primary_key=True, blank=True)
nombre      = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True)
descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True, null=True)
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
stock       = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
total_pedido =models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)

class Pedido(models.Model):
especialidad   = models.ForeignKey('Especialidad')
articulo       = models.ForeignKey('Articulo')
blank=True)
cantidad       = models.IntegerField(blank=True)    default='pendiente')

 def __str__(self):
return '{}'.format(self.especialidad, self.articulo, self.cantidad,   self.estado)

def update_total(sender, instance, **kwargs):
   instance.articulo.total_pedido += instance.cantidad
   instance.articulo.save()

# register the signal
signals.post_save.connect(update_total,sender=Pedido, dispatch_uid="update_stock_count")
```

views.py

```
def Cant_ingresar(request, id_pedido, id_especialidad):
especialidad = Especialidad.objects.get(id=id_especialidad)
pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=id_pedido)
if request.method == 'GET':
  form = PedidoEditForm(instance=pedido)
else:
  form = PedidoEditForm(request.POST, instance=pedido)
  if form.is_valid():
       form.save()
       """
       pedido.estado = 'pendiente'
       pedido.fecha_pedido = datetime.date.today()
       pedido.save()
       especialidad.estado='pendiente'
       especialidad.save()
       """
  return HttpResponseRedirect('/solicitar/lista_active/%s/' % id_especialidad)
return render(request, 'form.html', {'form':form, 'pedido':pedido, 'especialidad':especialidad, 'pedido':pedido})
```

As you can see, I first save the cantidad entered in the def of views.py, then in the model with the signals captured with post_save the amount and is summed with total_pedido of the Articulo model, this without problems, but adds two Times the same amount ie, enter a 3 and this goes to total_pedido as 6.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012887/django-post-save-signal-getting-called-twice-despite-uid). It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: can your format your code plase?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of `post_save` override `save`

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
    .....

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.articulo.total_pedido += self.cantidad
        self.articulo.save()
        super(Pedido, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I understand your point, although this example does not add anything to my total_pedido

Comment: Updated the views.py I think it's because I have more than one .save () according to your answer?

Comment: I already tried it! Thanks to your answer I cleared my mind, thank you, sir! thank you very much!

Comment: This will STILL mindlessly update `self.articulo.total_pedido` _each and every time_ `Pedido.save()` is called.

Comment: @itzmeontv sorry but no cigar - there's no recursion involved here, it's `Articulo.save()` that's getting called in the signal handler, not `Pedido.save()`. If that was the case the OP would get an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this double update happens when the currently commented out code is not commented out :

```
if form.is_valid():
   # this will call `pedido.save()` once
   form.save()
   # ...
   # adds some things to pedido...
   # ...
   # and here you're saving pedido a second time
   pedido.save()
```

So no suprise you get your signal handler called twice.

There are solutions to avoid this double `save` call (like passing  `commit=False` to `form.save()`) or (like suggested by itzmeontv) moving this update from a post_save signal to `pedido.save()` - **but this won't fix the underlying logical flaw**: this code will be executed **each and every time** `Pedido.save()` is called whatever the reason (like updating another unrelated field), each time adding `self.cantidad` over and over and over to `self.articulo.total_pedido`.

Here you have two solutions: either explicitely update `self.articulo` when you *know* it's needed (but this may not be very reliable), or instead of blindly adding to `articulo.total_pedido` ask `articulo` to completely recompute its value from scratch, ie:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class Articulo(models.Model):
   # ....

   def update_total_pedido(self):
       result = self.pedido_set.aggregate(total=Sum('cantidad'))
       self.total_articulo = result['total']
       self.save(update_fields=['total_articulo'])
```

and then in `Pedido`:

```
from django.db import transaction

class Pedido(models.Model):
    # ...
    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        with transaction.atomic():
            super(Pedido, self).save(*args, **kw)
            self.articulo.update_total_pedido()
```

Also note that if nothing prevents `Pedido` from being deleted, you may want to call `Articulo.update_total_pedido()` on deletion too.